# Using recursion, retrieving object name of nested object structure returns undefined

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, nested

I am trying to retrieve all the names of objects in a nested object tree/structure.

```
var testObj = {
      "name": "testObj",
      "version": "0.1.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "nameLvl1-1": {
          "version": "0.3.7",
          "dependencies": {
            "nameLvl2": {
              "version": "0.0.2"
            }
          }
        },
        "nameLvl1-2": {
          "version": "1.2.6"
        }
      }
    }
```

Currently I am iterating through the structure using recursion, but when I try to 'capture' the object names within the nested structure it returns 'undefined'

This is what I have currently:

```
const versionKeys2 = (obj) => {
  const result = []
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(x => {
    const key = x;
    const value = obj[x];
    if (key === 'version') {
      console.log(`${key} as key, ${obj[key]} as value, ${obj.name} as obj`)
      result.push(`${obj.name}@${obj[key]}`)
    }
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result.push(versionKeys2(value))
    }
  })
  return result
}
```

As an example which is logged to the console:

```
version as key, 0.3.7 as value, undefined as obj
```

For the first level it returns the name, but one past the level, into a nested object the '${obj.name}' returns undefined. Anyone know to address the object name beyond the first level?

EDIT: Expected results based on template literal string would look like so -- `[["dependencies"@"0.3.7"],["nameLvl1-1"@"0.3.7"],["nameLvl2"@"0.0.2"],["nameLvl1-2"@"1.2.6"]]`

Comment: result.push(versionKeys2(value)) is going to push an array into the array, not join them together.

Comment: obj.name <-- not every object has a name, hence undefined

Comment: What are you expecting as the actual output?

Comment: My intention is in the case of the first object found, 'dependencies', it would be passed in recursively and become the new object to be iterated on. That this would return the name of the object in that new execution environment. But my thoughts are that it 'obj.name' refers to the original object, not the one being passed into the new stack. Can confirm? @epascarello

Comment: If it is running correctly, what is the output for the test object?

Comment: This might be an interesting question.  But as epascarello has pointed out twice, we don't have enough information.  What should be returned and what should be logged for your sample input?

Comment: @epascarello going off the first nested object: 'dependencies' when applied in the template literal it would be -- [dependencies@"0.3.7"] -> ['object name here'@'version property here']

Comment: Set the exact output for that object. Giving the exact output expected would make this clear.

Comment: @epascarello: I think the update shows what's wanted.  If it weren't for the inconsistent structure of the root, this is a simple enough recursive problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change your input structure so that the first level is consistent with the nested ones, this could be fairly simple:

```js
const extract = (obj) => 
  Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
    ([name, {version, dependencies = []}]) => [
      `${name}@${version}`, 
      ...extract (dependencies)
    ])

const dependencyTree = {
   "testObj": {
      "version": "0.1.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "nameLvl1-1": {
          "version": "0.3.7",
          "dependencies": {
            "nameLvl2": {
              "version": "0.0.2"
            }
          }
        },
        "nameLvl1-2": {
          "version": "1.2.6"
        }
      }
    }
}

console .log (extract (dependencyTree))
```

While we could build something that wraps the above, doing something different for the root, it would be ugly.

Note that rather than

```js
{
    "name": "testObj",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "dependencies": {...)
}
```

this uses the following structure:

```js
{
   "testObj": {
       "version": "0.1.1",
       "dependencies": {...}
   },
   ...
}
```

**Note**, I wrote this before the last update with the expected output.  This would be easy enough to change in order to add an array wrapper around each string in the output, but I don't understand what they're for.

### Update

This version does the wrapping I mentioned:

```js
const extract = (obj) => 
  Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
    ([name, {version, dependencies = []}]) => [
      `${name}@${version}`, 
      ...extract (dependencies)
    ])
    
const weirdExtract = ({name, version, dependencies}) =>
  [`${name}@${version}`, ...extract(dependencies)]

const testObj = {name: "testObj", version: "0.1.1", dependencies: {"nameLvl1-1": {version: "0.3.7", dependencies: {nameLvl2: {version: "0.0.2"}}}, "nameLvl1-2": {version: "1.2.6"}}}

console .log (weirdExtract (testObj))
```

I still don't wrap the results in individual arrays.  But that would be simple to do.  If the arrays are supposed to nest in the same structure as the input, it would also not be too hard, but it doesn't look like that's what you want.

Comment: You're note is correct, the result as a nested array is just me being inexperienced! Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate or point to a resource that explains how you destructured the object? IE: '{name, version, dependencies}'

Comment: The first link from https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+destructuring is the [excellent reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from MDN.  The next few links are to decent tutorials.  Note that we're destructuring each array element returned by `Object.entries`.

Comment: You can think of it as shorthand so that you don't have to write this: ``const weirdExtract = (obj) => {const name = obj.name, version = obj.version, dependencies = obj.dependencies; return [`${name}@${version}`, ...extract(dependencies)]}``.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the nested names and check if the actual object contains a `name` property.

```js
const
    getNames = (object, name) => [
        `${object.name || name}@${object.version}`,
        ...Object
            .entries(object.dependencies || {})
            .flatMap(([k, v]) => getNames(v, k))
    ],
    testObj = { name: "testObj", version: "0.1.1", dependencies: { "nameLvl1-1": { version: "0.3.7", dependencies: { nameLvl2: { version: "0.0.2" } } }, "nameLvl1-2": { version: "1.2.6" } } },
    names = getNames(testObj);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: Could adding a name property to each object before passing it to the next stack work? I'd like to refer back to that name within a new stack. Something like object.name = `${value}`... although this sets the obj.name to [object Object]. (Referring to the second if statement in my code).

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  It would end up favoring an internal `name` property over the key pointing to that object on every node, not only the root; but that might be desirable behavior.  But unless that behavior is required, I would suggest if possible to change the input to be consistent at all levels, including the root.